# Spring does not load LDAP-XML config file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a prototype spring application to play with spring-security and LDAP. The application works with the internal LDAP-Server. But when I want to define an individual connection with a xml-config it doesn't work. More specific: The LdapTemplate which should be instantiated by the xml-config stays a null-object. Here is the code:

```
    public class UserRepo {

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;  //stays null
    public static final String BASE_DN = "dc=springframework,dc=org";

    //this works, but is not desired:
    public UserRepo() {
//      final GenericXmlApplicationContext appContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:ldap.xml");
//      appContext.refresh();
//      ldapTemplate = (LdapTemplate)appContext.getBean(LdapTemplate.class);
//      LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
//      lcs.setUrl("ldap://127.0.0.1:389/");
//      lcs.setUserDn(BASE_DN);
//      lcs.setDirObjectFactory(DefaultDirObjectFactory.class);
//      lcs.setAnonymousReadOnly(true);
//      lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
//      ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(lcs);
    }
```

My config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">

   <ldap:context-source
          id="contextSource"
          url="ldap://localhost:389"
          base="dc=example,dc=com"
          username="cn=Manager"
          password="secret" />

   <ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" />

   <bean id="userRepo" class="user.UserRepo">
      <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

I have put the ldap.xml one time in the src-dir and another time in the ressource-dir, both didn't work.

I hope you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add a @Component annotation to your UserRepo class and a proper annotation-config (or component-scan element if required). Since your commented-out code works, the LdapTemplate bean is created succesfully, and injected because you use a GenericXmlApplicationContext.  To test it with annotations you need an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext instead.

Comment: I added "@Component" to the class, didn't work. With "@AutoWired" above ldapTemplate->bean creation exception: http://pastebin.com/g9TW43tK I've forgotten to say, that the manual loading of the bean in the commented code results in an endless loop of bean loadings and hence in an endless loop of errors.

Comment: Do not mix injection with both @Autoewired annotation and xml configuration for the same bean. Get rifd of bean with id="userRepo from the xml file. Then make sure the xml config file is in the classpath and is referenced as part of the application context

Comment: I deleted now the xml config and tried an annotation config: http://pastebin.com/hG15ZFmY It doesN#t throw any error at startup but the ldapTemplate stays null.